# "No such file or directory" while in link path

Tags: linux, bash, ln

When compiling, I always place the build in a separate directory. For example:

```
mkdir build
cd ./build
(cd ..; ./bootstrap)
../configure
make
```

Since I have plenty of RAM the aim is to compile on a TMPFS.

The script gets the name of the project, uses it for the name for the directory created in `$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/build` and finally links it.

```
# setup-build.sh

#!/usr/bin/bash
set -e

my_project_name=$(basename $(pwd))
my_project_build_dir="$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/build/$my_project_name"
mkdir -p $my_project_build_dir
ln -s "$my_project_build_dir" "$(pwd)/build"
```

The script runs without a problem. But, when I do `cd ./build; ../configure` it returns an error: `bash: ../configure: No such file or directory`. The file most certainly does exist, but Bash can't find it!

Comment: can you try `cd ./build; echo $PWD`? this will tell you where you are when it try=ies to execute ../configure

Comment: You're not setting `$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR`. Is it exported in the script's parent environment? `declare -p XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` should include `-x` in its output if so.

Comment: @kkawabat `cd ./build; echo $PWD` returns `/home/gareth-anthony-hulse/Projects/prog/cpp-vulkan-triangle/build`.

Comment: @dennis-williamson `$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` defaults to `/run/user/$UID`. In my case `$UID` returns `1000`.

Comment: Ok, but is it exported?

Comment: @dennis-williamson Yes it is exported. `$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` is exported as soon as I login. Newly opened terminals always return `$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` with `/run/user/1000`.

Comment: OK, but you still didn't indicate whether `declare -p XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` includes `-x` in its output. Not being _exported_ is the primary suspect of the reason that the directory that your script is creating is not where you think it is. Also of note is that the argument to `mkdir` isn't quoted. There are other possibilities for why this script isn't working, however. Have you looked at what directories are _actually_ being created and _where_?

Comment: @DennisWilliamson I tried `declare -p XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` and it returns `declare -x XDG_RUNTIME_DIR="/run/user/1000"`. Did `touch test` in `/home/gareth-anthony-hulse/Projects/prog/cpp-vulkan-triangle/build`, went over to `/run/user/1000/build/cpp-vulkan-triangle` and found the test file.

Comment: This looks wrong: `(cd..; ./bootstrap)`.  There should at least be a space after the `..`

Comment: @StephenC `(cd..; ./bootstrap)` and `(cd.. ; ./bootstrap)` works equally well for me.

Comment: Sorry, I meant *before*.  There is no `cd..` command.

Comment: @StephenC Oh, I see now. I'll correct it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I altered the script to this:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
set -e

my_project_src_dir="$(pwd)"
my_project_name="$(basename $(pwd))"
my_project_build_dir="$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/build/$my_project_name"
mkdir -p "$my_project_build_dir"
ln -s "$my_project_build_dir" "$(pwd)/build"
cd "$my_project_build_dir"
echo "$my_project_src_dir" > "./project-src-dir.txt"
```

To compile I have to type `cd ./build; $(cat ./project-src-dir.txt)/configure; make`. This causes Bash complete to partial break, though. As in I can't TAB complete file names from `$my_project_src_dir` with this method, but TAB completion for arguments works fine. If`autoconf` is needed: `(cd $(cat ./project-src-dir.txt); ./bootstrap)`. If anyone has any other ideas I would still prefer to be able to just do `../configure`, although this will have to do for now.

**Edit:** Had to change `my_project_name="$(basename '$my_project_src_dir')` to `my_project_name="$(basename $(pwd))"` as it was taking `'$my_project_src_dir'` literally.

Comment: It was taking `'$my_project_src_dir'` literally because it's in single quotes. Switching those to double quotes will allow the variable to be expanded. Instead of running your script, you could _source_ it (`. scriptname` or `source scriptname`) and your variable will be available in your current environment allowing you to `cd ./build; "$my_project_src_dir/configure"; make` and `cd "$my_project_src_dir"; ./bootstrap` which might allow tab completion to work (you might need to leave out the quotes for that though).